# How do I Get The Selected Object type

Tags: python, 3d, maya, mel, pymel

I need to basically query and perform a few tasks based on the current selection with PYMEL, example:

```
from pymel.core import *    
s = selected()
if (s.selType() == 'poly'):
    #do something    
if (s.selType() == 'surface'):
    #do something    
if (s.selType() == 'cv'):
    #do something    
if (s.selType() == 'vertex'):
    #do something    
if (s.selType() == 'face'):    
    #do something
if (s.selType() == 'edge'):  
    #do something
if (s.selType() == 'curve'):
    #do something
```

I know that `selType()` is not an actual pymel function, I'd like to also take advantage of pymels api commands, not using standard mel commands if that makes sense.

Comment: It would help if you asked a question.

Comment: My title is pretty self explanitory along with the description, I need to find out 'HOW to get the selected object type'

Comment: Why would you chain many if commands, wouldnt it be much better to use a dictionary with functions?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, I've never used a dictionary and don't really know how it's purpose could be aided here @joojaa

Comment: A dictionairy is like a mapping function: `d = dict(a = 1, b = 2); d['a'] == 1; d['b'] == 2; d['c'] # Error`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyMEL will convert the selection list for you to nodes (unlike MEL, where everything is a simple datatype.) At least this is true with `ls` and related commands (`selected` is just `ls(sl=True)`.)

Everything in that list will be a subclass of `PyNode`, so you can rely on them having a method `nodeType`.

From there, it is easy to process each selection based on its type.

---

Components inherit from `pymel.core.Component`, and there is one class for each component type; `MeshVertex` for example.

You can use `isinstance(obj, type_sequence)` to filter out components:

```
filter(lambda x: isinstance(x, (pm.MeshVertex, pm.MeshEdge, pm.MeshFace)), pm.selected())
```

You can find them under the `general` section in the PyMEL docs.

Comment: Yes, but I couldn't get this to work on COMPONENTS, how can I find out  that from components that are selected?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the maya native filterExpand command to sort each into their respective types.
It essentially sifts through your selection and makes a list of the objects that correspond to the type you're looking for

For example:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

selection = cmds.ls(sl=1) # Lists the current selection and 
                          # stores it in the selection variable

polyFaces = cmds.filterExpand(sm=34) # sm (selectionMask) = 34 looks for polygon faces.
                                     # Store the result in polyFaces variable.

if (polyFaces != None): # If there was any amount of polygon faces.
   for i in polyFaces:  # Go through each of them.
      print(i)          # And print them out.
```

More info on the command and the filters corresponding int-value is in the python or mel command reference.